# How to enable error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence. in VS 2017 compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I would like for the VS compiler to raise an error when I define a string using escape literals. I am using `VS 2017 .NET 4.7.`
In the previous version `(VS2010)`, I was getting the error

> CS1009: unrecognized escape sequence.

if I defined a string like:

```
string foo="d:\test";
```

Currently, I didn't find any way to enable it. Tried to go to *Project Properties > Code Analysis* and open all rules, but couldn't find `CS1009` at all.

The reason why I would like this behavior is that after I defined a variable as I mentioned above, I, later on, used it in a `Path.Combine` method, the method that raised an exception due to illegal characters in path (tab).

I know that I can use `double backslashes` for escaping the `backslash` or even use `@` in front of the string, but I would like in the future not to be allowed to define a string like this.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks,
George

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you are looking for. `\t` is a valid escape sequence, meaning the tab character (as you know). The compiler does not know that this string happens to represent a file path where tab is not allowed.

Comment: That is correct.  it is actually no problem with the compiler itself or with the ruleset. If for example I try to use ''''Path.Combine("d:\test")''' I actually get the compiler error CS1009. This is because when creating a path, it cannot have invalid characters, like \n or \t

Comment: Then I would ask, if I have a variable defined as: string foo="d:\test\bar", how can I use this variable in a Path.Combine? Replace("//","////") doesn't work.

Comment: You can't as is. You'll have to prefix with `&` to disable the escapement interpretation, which is enabled by default, or else use escapes, i.e. `\\\`. That's just how it is.

Comment: Why is this a problem? - these are source code literals, after all, so it's not like you have a ton of them that need to be touched up manually ... or?

Comment: it is actually no problem. In my application I am currently hardcoding these paths and found out this issue. however, I will take this path from an xml file, and when reading from the xml file, the backslashes will be escaped. I was just curious how this can changed. @500-InternalServerError. I think in your previous comment you were referring to @ for disabling the escapement interpretation

Comment: Yes, doh! sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [code contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts) to specify, how to treat your string in compile-time. What you written here is perfectly valid string with TAB character.
Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099704/contract-assert-do-not-throw-compilation-error) too.